# Android - when should i convert dp to pixel

Tags: android

I have a custom action bar which i want a 80ish! height for it.
so i set my layouts height as 80dp with this code:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    xdpi = displayMetrics.xdpi;
x = Math.round(80 * (xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT))
... new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, x);
```

but its HUGE in xxxhdpi devices.
when i remove the conversion and use 80pixels value directly, it seems ok,
When to use converted dp and when to use direct pixel?

**Edit:**
the problem was somewhere else, i stored the "80dp" value in xml and retrieve it with "context.getResources().getDimension()", and it seems it converts the dimension to pixel internally and i was actually converting the converted value! I wonder if the same thing happens when using "sp" for fonts....

Comment: `dp` always refers to the **mdpi** density. And all graphics operations which are done *in code* are in `px` (while in xml layouts you can specify `dp`, directly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing the right thing it's just your conversion is wrong, it should be something like this:

```
float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
x = Math.round(80 * scale);
... new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, x);
```

Comment: the problem was somewhere else, i stored the "80dp" value in xml and retrieve it with "context.getResources().getDimension()", and it seems it converts the dimension to pixel internally and i was actually converting the converted value!

Comment: @Penman `dp` always refers to the **mdpi** density. And all graphics operations which are done *in code* are in `px` (while in xml layouts you can specify `dp`, directly).

Answer (score 0):

**Convert dp to pixel:**

```
public int dpToPx(int dp) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int px = Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));       
    return px;
}
```

**Convert pixel to dp:**

```
public int pxToDp(int px) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int dp = Math.round(px / (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
    return dp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pixel to Dp converter

```
public static float pxToDp(float px) {
        float densityDpi = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
        return px / (densityDpi / 160f);
    }
```

Dp to Pixel converter

```
 public static int dpToPx(int dp) {
        float density = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        return Math.round(dp * density);
    }
```